# How to run an exe with restricted permissions?

Tags: c#, permissions, exe

I am developing ,with C#, a server application that compiles and runs  the code of clients and i need to know if there is a way to run a exe in a process with restricted permissions(because the server can't trust client code).
The only permission that the file must have is to execute, all other permissions must be denied(I/O operations, access to internet, modify the registry, etc).

Comment: Hi I'm having this exact problem right now.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx) on MSDN which illustrates how a separate AppDomain could be created. And to even further increase the isolation between your server code and the client code this AppDomain could be created inside a separate process.